# Socket_read returning '1' ..?

Tags: php, sockets

I have recently started practicing with sockets on PHP and got an issue for which I find no documentation. Similar cases I've seen in C++, but not a clear answer to this. The code:

```
do {
    $input = socket_read($client, 12,PHP_BINARY_READ);
    echo $input;
} while(TRUE);
```

Is supposed to block on the socket (code for creation, bind, etc not included) and get either 12 bytes or whatever information is available from the other side.

Oddly I just get a '1' in the variable $input if 12 bytes are read.  If I send from the client side more than 12 bytes then I receive '1[REST_OF_DATA]' in the value of $input.

Any idea why this is happening?

If I change this to more data and to PHP_NORMAL_READ then I correctly receive the data.

PHP manual online does not say anything abou socket_read returning '1'..

**EDIT: Ok thanks for yout early answers :). I am saving to a file and reading (not echoing to browser) expecting any character.  I think I may have just discovered something that could be good if someone with knowledge of C++ sockets can verify. Anyways, my read code actually was this (not what I posted above):

```
do {
    $input = ($seq_id == 0) ? socket_read($client, 12,PHP_BINARY_READ) : socket_read($client,1024,PHP_BINARY_READ);
    echo $input;
} while(TRUE);
```

I was expecting 12 bytes at the first read, then chunks of 1024, reason for that condition check. The weird '1' comes from this.  If I replace that with the line I posted above the data is read normally.  In fact, even reading like this:

```
$input = ($seq_ID == 0) ? socket_read($client,12,PHP_BINARY_READ) : socket_read($client, 12,PHP_BINARY_READ);
```

Results in : 1st read = '1'  2nd read = correct data, 3rd read = correct data..

Comment: How do you know that the `1` comes from `$input`?

Comment: I saved that var on file and read it using vi

Comment: The code looks a bit misleading, `$seq_id` does not change. As you already changed it once, I'm starting to not trust your words that much. How much can the facts you present here be stressed? Can you please provide more details and automated tests and the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the comments above, yes $seq_id should increment. I just wanted to shorten the code. So now, the answer is not important for me anymore but remains an enigma, after upgrading my Ubuntu version this month I have been unable to replicate the error with the same script:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$address = "192.168.1.1";
$port = 3320;
$server_users = 3; 
$mysock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$bind_result = socket_bind($mysock,$address, $port) or die("Could not bind to address\n"); 
$listen_result = socket_listen($mysock, $server_users)  or die("Could not set up socket   listener\n");
$client = socket_accept($mysock) or die("Could not accept the connection to socket\n");

$seq_id =0;
do {
$input = ($seq_id == 0) ? socket_read($client, 12,PHP_BINARY_READ) : socket_read($client,1024,PHP_BINARY_READ);
echo $input;
} while(TRUE);
?>
```

I execute it in terminal:

```
$php -q myscript.php
```

And test it using netcat:

```
$netcat 192.168.1.1 3320
```

Note that the question is about socket_read returning 1 as it results, which is not documented anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The `12` you specify is the maximum length to read, so `12` can mean a return string of a size from 0-12 characters (binary string in PHP, 1 char = 1 byte).

Additionally as that can be binary, I suggest you use `var_dump` and a hexdump of the return string value to actually find out how many bytes were returned, echo might hide some control characters, your browser might hide whitespace.